# Read TIFF-File Header in C#

Tags: c#, tiff, geotiff

I'd like to know the size of a tiff-picture represented by an Image. This Information can be calculated from ImageWidth and ImageLength by using ResolutionUnit and X/Y-Resolution as Parameters. However I'm not capable to extract These Information out of a tiff-picture.

The description off the tiff-file-Header is found at [Adobe.](https://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/tiff/TIFF6.pdf)

As files can easily reach sizes above 400mb such as big maps, I'm looking for a way to only scan the Header of a TIFF-File to receive basic meta data like Resolution, ResolutionUnit, ResolutionX, ResolutionY and so on...

Do you know a good way to extract these information?

Comment: What's the problem in parsing the header if you know its format?

Comment: maybe I don't want to reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TiffBitmapDecoder class' CodecInfo property may give you what you want.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.tiffbitmapdecoder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx